# Include dmsetup in initrd

Tags: linux, disk-encryption, slackware, initrd

I am trying to install Slackware on an encrypted partition by following [these instructions](http://ftp.slackware.com/pub/slackware/slackware-14.1/README_CRYPT.TXT). However, when I issue

```
mkinitrd -c -k 3.2.29-smp -m ext3 -f ext3 -r cryptroot -C /dev/sdx1
```

the resulting *initrd* image does not contain `dmsetup`. This leads to a failure at boottime where it complains that it could not find `/sbin/dmsetup`. I have verified that `dmsetup` exists in `/sbin` of the installed root filesystem but for some reason it does not get picked up by `mkinitrd`.

Is there any way to tell `mkinitrd` to include `dmsetup` in its image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `/sbin/mkinitrd` it would appear that you also have to (as a quick solution) add `-L` for LVM support which will cause dmsetup to be pulled in. That indeed seems to be an omission on part of the documentation.